# Can limits of be computed via Fourier transforms

Tags: limits, fourier-analysis

Suppose, we want to find a   limit of $f(t)$ or $t^n f(t)$ as $t \to \infty$.   Can these limits be computed via fourier tranform of $f(t)$?

Comment: There is a correlation between fourier coefficients and analyticity. Namely, the smoother $f(t)$ is, the faster its fourier transform decays. In reverse, the the faster $f(t)$ decays, the smoother its fourier transform is. But I don't know if you can use that to do explicit limit calculations on the original function.

Comment: @falasfa how do you state this formally?

Comment: @felasfa well for example if $\hat{f} \in L^2$ then $f \in L^2$ and $\lim_{ t \to \infty} f(n+a) =  0$ for almost every $a \in [0,1)$. In the same way, if $\frac{d}{d\xi^n}\hat{f} \in L^2$ then $t^n f \in L^2$ and $t^n f(t) \to 0$ on almost every sequence $\to \infty$

Comment: @user1952009, point well taken. The equivalence stated is true for $f\in L^{1}$. I can't recall but more conditions are needed for $f\in L^{2}$.

Comment: @Boby, for eg look page 4,5 here math.gmu.edu/~dwalnut/teach/Math772/Fall07/772f07lec02.pdf

Comment: @felasfa what you write is unclear. And for $\hat{f} \in L^1$, you automatically have $f \in L^\infty$ and $f(t) \to 0$. The converse is not true.

Answer (score -1):

A function $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ iff there is a function $g$ that is absolutely integrable on $[a,b]$ and satisfies
$$
                  f(y)-f(x) = \int_{x}^{y} g(t)dt,\;\;\; x,y \in [a,b].
$$
Equivalently, a function $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ if it is continuous on $[a,b]$, has a derivative a.e. on $[a,b]$, the derivative is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $f(y)-f(x)=\int_{x}^{y}f'(t)dt$ for all $x,y\in [a,b]$.

The Fourier transform is perfectly tied to the differentiation operator as follows: $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is absolutely continuous on every finite interval, with $f' \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ iff
$$
               \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2+|\xi\hat{f}(\xi)|^2d\xi < \infty.
$$
And $f$ is n-times absolutely continuous with $f,f',\cdots,f^{(n)}\in L^2$ iff
$$
          \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2+|\xi\hat{f}(\xi)|^2+\cdots+|\xi^{n}\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2}d\xi < \infty,\\
    \mbox{ or } \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+|\xi|^{2n})|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2d\xi < \infty.
$$
That's about it when it comes to iff conditions.

Comment: Sorry, how does this answer my question?